# Removing non-displaying characters from a file

Tags: bash, unix, shell, grep

```
$ cat weirdo 
Lunch now?
$ cat weirdo | grep Lunch
$ vi weirdo
  ^@L^@u^@n^@c^@h^@ ^@n^@o^@w^@?^@
```

I have some files that contain text with some non-printing characters like `^@` which cause my `grep`s to fail (as above).

How can I get my `grep` work? Is there some way that does not require altering the files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your file is encoded in UTF-16 rather than an 8-bit character set.  The '^@' is a notation for ASCII NUL '\0', which usually spoils string matching.

One technique for loss-less handling of this would be to use a filter to convert UTF-16 to UTF-8, and then using `grep` on the output - hypothetically, if the command was 'utf16-utf8', you'd write:

```
utf16-utf8 weirdo | grep Lunch
```

As an appallingly crude approximation to 'utf16-utf8', you could consider:

```
tr -d '\0' < weirdo | grep Lunch
```

This deletes ASCII NUL characters from the input file and lets `grep` operate on the 'cleaned up' output.  In theory, it might give you false positives; in practice, it probably won't.

Comment: I don't know about utf16-utf8, but `iconv` should be available everywhere: `iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 weirdo`

Comment: @DarkDust: thanks - `iconv` is a lot less hypothetical than `utf16-utf8`.  Of course, as a shell script, `utf16-utf8` is now a trivial one-liner: `exec iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 "$@"`.

Answer (score 5):

The `tr` command is made for that:

```
cat weirdo | tr -cd '[:print:]\r\n\t' | grep Lunch
```

Answer (score 2):

You may have some success with the `strings(1)` tool like in:

```
strings file | grep Launch
```

See `man strings` for more details.

Comment: The `strings` command normally works on sequences of printable characters above a certain threshold - 4 by default.  In the example shown, each printable is separated from the next by NUL, so strings won't find anything.  I suppose that `strings -n 1` (or `-s 1` in some versions) might do the trick...except that each output string is normally separated from the next by a newline.  So, you'd probably have to delete the newlines, which also makes things unreadable in a different way (the whole file always gets printed if it matches).

Comment: sysinternals has strings also that prints displayable characters: `Strings v2.51
Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

usage: strings [-a] [-f offset] [-b bytes] [-n length] [-o] [-q] [-s] [-u] <file or directory>
-a     Ascii-only search (Unicode and Ascii is default)
-b     Bytes of file to scan
-f     File offset at which to start scanning.
-o     Print offset in file string was located
-n     Minimum string length (default is 3)
-q     Quiet (no banner)
-s     Recurse subdirectories
-u     Unicode-only search (Unicode and Ascii is default)`

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
awk '{gsub(/[^[:print:]]/,"") }1' file
```